# Qt use palette color in stylesheet

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpalette

In qt you normally set the color of a `QWidget` with the `QPalette`.

Example:

```
QPalette palette = new QPalette();
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Base, this->palette().backgorund());

QLineEdit *line = new QLineEdit();
line->setPalette(palette);
```

Now I have a little problem. It is not possible to change the bordercolor of a QLineEdit with the `QPalette`. That means, that I have to use a `QStyleSheet`.

Example:

```
QLineEdit *line = new QLineEdit();
line.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid green");
```

But now I can't set the basecolor of the QLineEdit with `QPalette`, because the background-color of QLineEdit is not longer connected to `QPalette::base`.
That means, that the following code wouldn't change the `background-color` of the `QLineEdit`:

```
QPalette palette = new QPalette();
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Base, this->palette().backgorund());

QLineEdit *line = new QLineEdit();
line->setPalette(palette);
line->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid green");
```

But it is not possible, to define the `background-color` of the QLineEdit in the StyleSheet, because the `background-color` of the `QLineEdit` have to be dynamically.

My question: How to connect the background-color of the `QLineEdit` with `QPalette::base` to define the `background-color` of `QLineEdit` dynamically with `QPalette`?

Comment: Why can't you simply create/format a `QString` containing the required background and border values?

Comment: I don't know, what you mean. Do you mean, I should create a class inherit from QString with a field for background and a field for the border? - There is no background and border property in QString, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just construct the required `QString` at runtime...

```
auto style_sheet = QString("border: 1px solid green;"
                           "background-color: #%1;")
  .arg(QPalette().color(QPalette::Base).rgba(), 0, 16);
```

The above should result in a `QString` such as...

```
border: 1px solid green;
background-color: #ffffffff;
```

Then...

```
line->setStyleSheet(style_sheet);
```

Comment: Ah ofcourse now I understand what you mean. That's a easy and great idea. - Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively:

```cpp
line->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral(
    "border: 1px solid green;"
    "background-color: palette(base);"
));
```

Reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#paletterole

Using `PaletteRole` also lets the CSS be in a separate file/source.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The currently accepted answer is more like "generate a style sheet with colors copied from a palette object". This is (according to me) quite far from how the question is stated (and what I want to do as well). This said, I can't seem to get this to work (all my colors come out black). Does anyone know of a working example somewhere? I couldn't find any... :(

Comment: Slight correction, the colors don't come out black, but the palette colors I've set seem to be ignored and I get some default palette...

Comment: @pythonator When using CSS on a widget, the widget's default or assigned palette may be ignored (esp. in the cases or backgrounds/borders/frames). In such cases the `PaletteRole` seems best used when referring to the default app `QPalette` (optionally set with QApplication::setPalette()`). The exact behavior, and especially how the palette colors propagate (or not) can depend on the Qt style being used (e.g. "fusion" or "windows", etc). "Fusion" is the most flexible and predictable in terms of QPalette inheritance, and also for mixing it with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my situation. Because I only want to mask the border, and don't want to color it, I can use the method `QLineEdit::setFrame(bool)`. But what is, if I want to color the frame like in my example above? I didn't find a solution for that so far. I am happy about every answer.